# Custom Admin Module Not Showing in Magento2

Tags: adminhtml, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta

I am learning Magento2 and I have created adminhtml test module it's not working.

Can you please suggest me where i went wrong?

my code is:

**app\etc\config.php**

```
'modules' =>
        array (
        'Magento_Test' => 1, 

        ),
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Test\Block\Adminhtml;
class Test extends use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
{
    public function _prepareLayout(){
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute() {
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Test" schema_version="2.0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="test" frontName="test" >
            <module name="Magento_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\etc\acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Test::test" title="Custom Module" sortOrder="40">
                    <resource id="Magento_Test::item" title="New Record" sortOrder="40" />
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::config">
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Test::test" title="test" module="Magento_Test" sortOrder="40" resource="Magento_Test::test"/>
        <add id="Magento_Test::item" title="New Record" module="Magento_Test" sortOrder="40" parent="Magento_Test::test" action="test/index/" resource="Magento_Test::item"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\view\adminhtml\layout\test_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test" name="test_test" template="test/test.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app\code\Magento\Test\view\adminhtml\templates\test\test.phtml**

```
<h1>Magento 2 Custom Module </h1>
```

**url: http://localhost/magento-2/admin/test/index/index/**

it's redirecting dashboard page while entering above url.

Can you please suggest me where i went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the module enable in store advance? Did you clear cache (`rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*`)?

Comment: @R.S, Yes I have cleared. Still not executing my module. Is it right my code? or something went wrong?

Comment: Side note: Please don't use "Magento_Test" as a module name in practice. "Magento_*" is reserved for use by Magento. Use your own vendor name (I use "AlanKent" for my own play projects.)

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples? Might be something useful there to learn from.

Comment: In particular, the "newpage" sample is very close to what you are doing (but for a store front page instead of admin).

Comment: @AlanKent, i have done store front page. Now i need to know backend (admin) page. if you have any example or links for this? plz... provide

Comment: I copied your files to my tree.  I deleted var/*. I got an error talking about the module.xml file (in developer mode) - I changed "schema_version" to "setup_version" and then ran "magento setup:upgrade".

I went to the Admin page and selected Store / Configuration / Advanced / Advanced and expanded "disable module output". The Magento_Test module was visible. So its being loaded.

I played a bit longer, but had other things to get done. But I certainly came away with ideas for improvements that would make debugging easier!!

Comment: @AlanKent, Yes, now it's working fine. it's not working directly by entering url. I have created menu and acl files and then clicked on menu item it's working. Anyway Thank you for your suggestions and valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

`routers.xml` should be `routes.xml`. [See this file as example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml)

Comment: Still not executing my module. Is it right my code? or something went wrong?

Comment: Clear the cache after the filename change. If that doesn't work I have no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've created menu.xml in /view/adminhtml

`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_MyModule::mymodule_index" title="My Module" module="Vendor_MyModule" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="mymodule/index" resource="Vendor_MyModule::index"/>
    </menu>
</config>`

I copied this from cms module and updated it with my module information. 
I can see the item under Content -> Elements in admin menu.